# Graph traversal - finding and returning the shortest distance

Tags: java, graph, queue, traversal, breadth-first-search

I am using a Breadth first search in a program that is trying to find and return the shortest path between two nodes on an unweighted digraph.

My program works like the wikipedia page psuedo code

The algorithm uses a queue data structure to store intermediate results as it traverses the graph, as follows:
Enqueue the root node
Dequeue a node and examine it
If the element sought is found in this node, quit the search and return a result.
Otherwise enqueue any successors (the direct child nodes) that have not yet been discovered.
If the queue is empty, every node on the graph has been examined – quit the search and return "not found".
If the queue is not empty, repeat from Step 2.

So I have been thinking of how to track number of steps made but I am having trouble with the limitations of java (I am not very knowledgeable of how java works). I originally was thinking that I could create some queue made up of a data type I made that stores steps and nodes, and as it traverses the graph it keeps track of the steps. If ever the goal is reached just simply return the steps.

I don't know how to make this work in java so I had to get rid of that idea and I moved on to using that wonky Queue = new LinkedList implementation of a queue. So basically I think it is a normal integer queue, I couldn't get my data type I made to work with it.

So now I have to find a more basic approach so I tried to use a simple counter, this doesn't work because the traversal algorithm searches down many paths before reaching the shortest one so I had an idea. I added a second queue that tracked steps, and I added a couple counters. Any time a node is added to the first queue I add to the counter, meaning I know that I am inspecting new nodes so I am not a distance further away. Once all those have been inspected I can then increase the step counter and any time a node is added to the first queue I add the step value to the step queue. The step queue is managed just like the node queue so that when the goal node is found the corresponding step should be the one to be dequeued out.

This doesn't work though and I was having a lot of problems with it, I am actually not sure why.

I deleted most of my code in panic and frustration but I will start to try and recreate it and post it here if anyone needs me to.

Were any of my ideas close and how can I make them work? I am sure there is a standard and simple way of doing this as well that I am not clever enough to see.

Answer (score 0):

Code would help. What data structure are you using to store the partial or candidate solutions? You say your using a queue to store nodes to be examined, but really the objects stored in the queue should wrap some structure (e.g. `List`) that indicates the nodes traversed to get to the node to be examined. So, instead of simple `Node`s being stored in the queue, some more complex object would be needed to make available the information necessary to know the complete path taken to that point. A simple node would only have information about itself, and it's children. But if you're examining node X, you also need to know how you arrived to node X. Just knowing node X isn't enough, and the only way (I know of) to know the path taken to node X is to store the path in the object that represents a "partial solution" or "candidate solution". If this is done, then finding the length of the path is trivial, because it's just the length of this list (or whichever data structure chosen). Hope I'm making some sense here. If not, post code and I'll take a look.

**EDIT**

These bits of code help show what I mean (they're by no means complete):

```
public class Solution {
    List<Node> path;
}

Queue<Solution> q;
```

NOT

```
Queue<Node> q;
```

**EDIT 2**

If all you need is the length of the path, and not the path, per se, then try something like this:

```
public class Solution {
    Node node; // whatever represents a node in you algorithm.
    int len; // the length of the path to this node.
}

// Your queue:
LinkedList<Solution> q;
```

With this, before enqueuing a candidate solution (node), you do something like:

```
Solution sol = new Solution();
sol.node = childNodeToEnqueue;
sol.len = parentNode.len + 1;
q.add(sol);
```

Comment: I think I understand, I need to create linked lists that store the path...but how do I do that? I need to iteratively create a potentially infinite amount of linked lits? How do I name and instantiate them iteratively? Or would this be more like an array the size of my graph that is composed of linked lists?

Comment: Say you have a graph, root node A with children B and C (a[b,c]), and B and C have children, and so forth. With each partial solution, you store an array or list or whatever. To start the algorithm, this list would contain A. When examining B the list would contain A,B. If be had a child D, then at D, the list would contain A,B,D, etc. You add an additional node to the path of nodes just before enqueuing a node.

Comment: But, the number of list needed is not infinite. I could be quite large, but it's a function of the number of nodes in the graph. In essence, you don't enqueue nodes, you enqueue paths taken to get to the nodes. And these paths aren't all created together, they're created with each child node that you want to enqueue.

Comment: But how to I add alternate paths?

Comment: What do you mean? If you're examining B, with a child D, then before enqueuing D, the algorithm says, "Ok, I'm at B, and the path I've taken so far is A,B. So I'll add D to the end of that list --> enqueue A,B,D."

Comment: But what if C had children D E F so now my potential paths are ABCD, ABCE, and ABCF

Comment: Exactly, and each distinct list gets enqueued. See my edit. Doing it this way, you don't enqueue nodes, you enqueue lists of nodes.

Comment: I don't know how to make a queue of lists. That was my original problem I was having.

Comment: That could be as simple as `LinkedList<List<Node>>`.

Comment: So that is a LinkedList that has as an element a list of type node? I am not familiar with List and node so I will have to read about it.

Comment: Well, `Node` is just assuming you had a class by that name already, it's not a Java class. [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) (which you already know I suppose) is one implementation of [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). And the other list you use could be any of the implementations of the `List` interface. To pick one, [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` are standard java classes.

Comment: On second thought this seems overly complex, why do I store the path taken? All I need to know is the distance.

Comment: How would you know the distance if you don't keep track of the path of each candidate solution?

Comment: Don't follow the path just keep the integer value of the path.

Comment: @YKQ56, right. Did you check the second edit of my answer? I think that does what you want, unless I'm still misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution in order to track distance during a traversal is to add a simple array (or a map if you vertices are not indexed by integers).

Here is pseudo code algorithm:

```
shortest_path(g, src, dst):
  q = new empty queue
  distances = int array of length order of g
  for i = 0 to order: distances[i] = -1
  distances[src] = 0
  enqueue src in q
  while q is not empty:
    cur = pop next element in q
    if cur is dst: return distances[dst]
    foreach s in successors of cur in g:
      if distances[s] == -1:
        distances[s] = distances[cur] + 1
        enqueue s in q
  return not found
```

Note: order of a graph is the number of vertices

You don't need special data structures, the queue can just contains vertices' id (probably integers). In Java, LinkedList class implements the Queue interface, so it's a good candidate for your queue. For the distances array, if your vertices are identified by integers an integer array is enough, otherwise you need a kind of map.

You can also separate the vertex tainting (the -1 in my algo) using a separate boolean array or a set, but it's not really necessary and will waste some space.

If you want the path, you can also do that with a simple parent array: for each vertex you store its parent in the traversal, just add parent[s] = cur when you enqueue the successor. Then retrieving the path (in reverse order) is a simple like this:

```
path = new empty stack
cur = dst
while cur != src:
  push cur in path
  cur = parent[cur]
push src in path
```

And there you are …